# Json Unmarshal reflect.Type

Tags: json, reflection, go

[Here is the code](http://play.golang.org/p/rQ6qSAh19R):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "encoding/json"
    "reflect"
)

var(
    datajson []byte
)

type User struct {
    Name string
    Type reflect.Type
}

func MustJSONEncode(i interface{}) []byte {
    result, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return result
}
func MustJSONDecode(b []byte, i interface{}) {
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, i)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
func Store(a interface{}) {
    datajson = MustJSONEncode(a)
    fmt.Println(datajson)
}

func Get(a []byte, b interface{}) {
    MustJSONDecode(a, b)
    fmt.Println(b)
}

func main() {
    dummy := &User{}
    david := &User{Name: "DavidMahon"}
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(david)
    david.Type = typ
    Store(david)
    Get(datajson, dummy)
}
```

I can successfully marshal `reflect.Type` but when I do the reverse, it panics. I know `reflect.Type` is an interface. So what am I doing wrong here? How can I store a `reflect.Type` value in json and then retrieve back safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't make sense. There is no way for the JSON package to know what data should be decoded. This interface might be implemented by a `struct{}` type, an `int` type and maybe a `struct{ Value1, Value2 int }` type. Even worse, there might be other types as well, that are aren`t even part of your binary (missing imports, dead code elimination, etc.). So, which type do you expect to get back from JSON?

You probably need to find another way. For example, you could implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface, unmarshal an identifier and use that identifier to unmarshal the following data into a concrete type. The switch statement that you will probably need for that, will also ensure that the concrete type is part of your binary (since you are using it).

But there is probably an easier solution. Your question doesn't tell what you want to archive though. Would it be enough to just marshal / unmarshal the name of the type as string?

Comment: I want to store data(as in object of certain type) into database. In order to store that data, I need to marshal it into json. My object contains reflection details (`Type` of object). So basically I can store any data of any type and get it back. Database is a custom one that I am using it. I just want a way to store data of type `reflect.Type` and get it back safely.

Comment: I thought of storing the name of the type, but then how would I get concrete Type from that? I am perplexed

Comment: If you want to store objects of different types in your database, you could add a "Type" field that contains just the name of the type. Then you would have to decode the type field first (just decode into a `struct {Type string}`) before you decode your real object based on that type.

Comment: What api shall I use to decode a string into `reflect.Type`? I am unable to find one.

Comment: There is none. Use a `map[string]reflect.Type`. You need  such a map anyway to ensure that those types are part of your binary... `init()` functions might be useful to populate the map.

Comment: I mean at the end it needs to be unmarshalled. And thats where it panics. So it doesnt matter whether you store it in a map or elsewhere

Comment: May be that needs to be saved without using json.

Comment: Once your know the reflect.Type you can unmarshal into `x := reflect.New(typemap[name])` which will work fine.

Comment: Yes I need to store that map without using json marshalling. That is the only way. Thanks

Comment: Aah...I cannot store `reflect.Type` in the database like that. It needs to be marshalled. How do you store such a `type` anyways?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35670/discussion-between-tux21b-and-minty)